# Error while Indexing document using SolrJ API

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.*
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.*;
import org.apache.solr.common.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Response{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException
  {
    /*String host =  "localhost:9983",localkey = (""+Math.random());
    Search srch = new Search(host,localkey, "Search");
    Update updt = new Update(host,localkey, "Update");
    srch.start();
    updt.start();*/
    String zkHost = "http://localhost:9983";
    CloudSolrClient server = new CloudSolrClient(zkHost);
    server.setDefaultCollection("Test");
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("id", "1234");
    doc.addField("name", "A lovely summer holiday");
    server.add(doc);
    server.commit();
    }
}
```

My Solr Cloud is running on port 8983, 7575, 8984, 7576 and Zookeeper is running at 9983.
I am getting the following error while running the code:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create HttpClient instance. 
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil$HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtil.java:393)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.<init>(CloudSolrClient.java:189)
    at Response.main(Response.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil$HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtil.java:391)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.<init>(CloseableHttpClient.java:58)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.<init>(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:116)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

Can someone tell me how to get it through? I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: You seem to be missing the Apache logging jar in your classpath.Without that you probably won't get any decent logging of the error either..

Comment: You mean org-apache-commons-logging?

Comment: possibly you need this: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

You have **logger** and **http connection** problem. and you have to add these following dependencies into your project pom.xml to solve this problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it will help you :)